# why does if-else not work if 'else' is on the next line after 'if', but works inside a loop

Tags: r

I have noticed that an if-else condition does not work if else is on the next line, as follows. Isn't this bad?

```
i = 4;
if(i<5)
{
print("less than 5")
}
else
{
print ("greater than or equal to 5")
}
```

This can be corrected as follows

```
i = 4;
if(i<5)
{
print("less than 5")
}else
{
print ("greater than or equal to 5")
}
```

However, the same works(placing 'else' in the next line after 'if') if it's inside a for loop.

```
i = 0;
for(i in 1:10)
{
 if(i<5)
 {
  print("less than 5")
 }
 else
 {
  print ("greater than or equal to 5")
 }
}
```

Comment: From `?"if"`, *...you should not have a newline between } and else to avoid a syntax error in entering a if ... else construct at the keyboard or via source.*

Comment: @RichardScriven , thanks. But why does the same work inside the for loop?

Comment: Because the interpreter was waiting for you to close the `for` loop brackets, so everything inside has been defined completely by the time you close the loop.  Whereas at the prompt, once you close the first set of `if` brackets, the interpreter interprets that as the end of the statement.  The answer in the linked question explains that as well